# Best way to create and paint graphics in Javascript for game development?

Tags: javascript, html

If you were wanting to create a game in JavaScript with nothing other than just html code. What would be the best way of creating the underlying foundation to paint the graphics on. I am going to try and make a centipede game or asteroid game and I was told to use a canvas and paint all of my graphics onto the canvas. Is this the best way or is there other ways that would work better.

Class:

```
<body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="" bgcolor='black'>
   Test

   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="600" style="border:1px solid #00FFFF;">
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas>

</body
```

Comment: for all the possible alternatives, please research using google.com or the lile. Rather than for asking general questions, SO is more for after you decided on the approach you want to go with, started programming, and then ran into problems with code not doing what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

the best thing to use for javascript is definitely `<canvas>` for graphics - I actually made a centipede and an astroid game using it as well as others like checkers and a cookie clicker - definitely check out [CreateJs](http://www.createjs.com) and other canvas tutorials for more info, bro!

Comment: It would be cool if you could provide some support for your claim, e.g. comparing canvas against alternative approaches. As a start: What makes canvas "better" than SVG for games?

Comment: for one - canvas is far more faster than svg - as it only needs one tag for a decent application as claimed by "http://smus.com/canvas-vs-svg-performance/" and it is much easier to write to one div's context instead of multiple svgs - which constantly need their widths and heights set.

Comment: You don't have to constantly set the width and height of svg elements. If you want to animate them, you just have to translate them. I agree that `canvas` generally performs better, but it also depends on how many elements you are actually drawing. SVG has the advantage that you do more advance interactions more easily. So, I guess my point is that there isn't really a "best", it depends on what *exactly* you want to do.

Comment: what is SVG? can you provide a link to a couple of example games and maybe even some source code to test on.